# how to import image from JS file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am practicing on the webpack project. I got the error while I am importing the img file. I am new for webpack. I have installed the "image-webpack-loader" but still got the error.

Here is the webpack.config.js code

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const config = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                use: 'babel-loader',
                test: /\.js$/,
            },
            {
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    loader: 'css-loader'
                }),
                test: /\.css$/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g | png | gif |svg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 40000
                        }
                    },
                    'image-webpack-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

And Here is the image_viewer.js file

```
import '../assets/big.jpg';
import '../assets/small.jpg';

import '../styles/image_viewer.css';

const image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/400';

document.body.appendChild(image);
```

I can't find the solution for this issue. You can see the issue. The style.css and build.js is properly bundled but when I work for image it does not work got some error which I have mentioned below.

```
> webpack

keywords if/then/else require v5 option
Hash: 5ba37842c394273b5247
Version: webpack 2.2.0-rc.0
Time: 2330ms
    Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js   4.38 kB       0  [emitted]  main
style.css  41 bytes       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./src/image_viewer.js 452 bytes {0} [built]
   [1] ./src/sum.js 177 bytes {0} [built]
   [2] ./assets/big.jpg 235 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
   [3] ./assets/small.jpg 237 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
   [4] ./styles/image_viewer.css 41 bytes {0} [built]
   [5] ./src/index.js 303 bytes {0} [built]
    + 1 hidden modules

ERROR in ./assets/small.jpg
Module parse failed: I:\Javascript & Angular & Node\webpack\assets\small.jpg Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./src/image_viewer.js 7:13-43
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./assets/big.jpg
Module parse failed: I:\Javascript & Angular & Node\webpack\assets\big.jpg Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./src/image_viewer.js 3:11-39
 @ ./src/index.js
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin:
       [1] ./~/css-loader!./styles/image_viewer.css 204 bytes {0} [built]
        + 1 hidden modules
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! jsmodule@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the jsmodule@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Engraved\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-27T10_29_34_980Z-debug.log
```

My webpack version is "webpack": "^2.2.0-rc.0".

Comment: You may need file-loader.Also it is better to start with webpack v4 since lot of things have changed from webpack 2

Comment: I have installed "file-loader" module from npm but still got the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer for this error. I have researched more and found the issue. It is the little issue by which I had mad.

The issue was that to add space to images extension which I have mentioned in the code. See below the line

```
test: /\.(jpe?g | png | gif |svg)$/
```

This line got mad me. You can not give the space between them.

```
test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/ - This is the correct.
```